# Django Rest Framework- Writable nested serializers error

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to create a quiz app, i'm a beginner in dajango and rest, and I'm trying to create a serializer for creating new question with choices, i also not understand well how writable nested serializers working, if some one can give a working example

models.py:

```
class Question(models.Model):
    quiz = models.ForeignKey(Quiz, related_name="question")
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.question 

class Choice(models.Model):
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, related_name="choice")
    choice = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    correct_answer = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.choice
```

serializers.py:

```
class createChoiceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Choice
        fields = ('choice','correct_answer',)

class createQuestionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    choices = createChoiceSerializer()
    class Meta:
        model = Question

    def create(self, validated_data):
        choices_data = validated_data.pop('choices')
        question = Choice.objects.create(**validated_data)
        for choice in choices_data:
            try:
                choice = Choice.objects.get(name=choice["name"])
            except Choice.DoesNotExist:
                choice = Choice.objects.create(**choice)
            question.choices.add(choice)
        return question
```

when i write the question and choice i got an error:
ValueError at /questions/create

Cannot assign "u"what's your name"": "Choice.question" must be a "Question" instance.

Comment: Choice.objects.create(**validated_data) why do you assign this to question? Should it be Question.objects.create(**validated_data) ?

Comment: @brsbilgic whatever variable! do u think this is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

question = Choice.objects.create(**validated_data)

`question` is a `Choice` instance and  `question.choices.add(choice)` basically adds `Choice` to `Choice` instance.

You may try `Question.objects.create(**validated_data)`. I'm not sure if this works but at least solves the error you encounter now.